# How to generate dict from list of lists with possible empty values?

Tags: python

I have list of lists: `dep = [['ArithmeticError'], ['ZeroDivisionError', 'ArithmeticError'], ['OSError'], ['FileNotFoundError', 'OSError']]` and I need to convert it to dict like: `dep = {'ArithmeticError': None, 'ZeroDivisionError': 'ArithmeticError', 'OSError': None, 'FileNotFoundError': 'OSError'}`. Also it possible to have list of strings as value with  some names of errors.
I saw variants with dict(), but it doesn't work for me because empty values is possible.
I tried to use `dep = dict(dep)`, but I have error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required".

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Is what you're really after: `{'ArithmeticError': ['ZeroDivisionError'], 'OSError': ['FileNotFoundError']}` ? That's straight forward if only two deep - otherwise, you're after what looks like a dependency graph...

Comment: @JonClements, yes, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `None` to the end of each sublist, then take the first two items.

```
dep = dict((sublist + [None])[:2] for sublist in dep)
```

e.g. using [**`pprint`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) to print nicely

```
>>> dep = [['ArithmeticError'],
...        ['ZeroDivisionError', 'ArithmeticError'],
...        ['OSError'],
...        ['FileNotFoundError', 'OSError']]

>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> result = dict((sublist + [None])[:2] for sublist in dep)

>>> pprint(result)
{'ArithmeticError': None,
 'FileNotFoundError': 'OSError',
 'OSError': None,
 'ZeroDivisionError': 'ArithmeticError'}
```

edit: To perhaps be clearer we could also use [**`itemgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to give a name to what we're returning:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> first_two = itemgetter(0, 1)

>>> first_two(['ZeroDivisionError', 'ArithmeticError', None])
('ZeroDivisionError', 'ArithmeticError')
```

Then the above solution becomes:

```
>>> result = dict(first_two(sublist + [None]) for sublist in dep)
```

Comment: Liked your clever answer but in terms of readability I always found a slicing a bit more time to understand when skimming over a code snippet.

Comment: @M.A.K.Simanto I've updated with an example using `itemgetter` which is perhaps more readable.

Comment: Great, easier to read than a generator now, will definitely try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
dep = [['ArithmeticError'], ['ZeroDivisionError', 'ArithmeticError'],
   ['OSError'], ['FileNotFoundError', 'OSError']]

dep_dict = {}

for val in dep:
    if len(val) == 1:
        dep_dict[val[0]] = None
    else:
        dep_dict[val[0]] = val[1]
```

This works by making the dictionary `dep_dict` and assigning it's keys to be the values of `dep` and their values to either `None` or the second item in the corresponding list.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small check and a generator

```
dep = dict((a[0],a[1]) if len(a)>1 else (a[0],None) for a in dep)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator with basic conditional.

```
dep_dict = {i[0]: None if len(i) == 1 else i[1]   for i in dep}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably easier ways, but you can use:

```
dep = [['ArithmeticError'], ['ZeroDivisionError', 'ArithmeticError'], ['OSError'], ['FileNotFoundError', 'OSError']]

d={}
for x in dep:
    if len(x) == 1:
        d[x[0]] = None
    elif len(x) == 2:
        d[x[0]] = x[1]

print(d)
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'ArithmeticError': None, 'ZeroDivisionError': 'ArithmeticError', 'OSError': None, 'FileNotFoundError': 'OSError'}
```